# Get the parameter part of an URI using Windows::Fundation::Uri

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using Windows::Fundation::Uri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx) to handling Uris.

However I couldn't find a good way to get the parameter part of the URI out as a string, for example.

`http://www.example.com?q=test&q2=test2`

is there a good way to get `q=test&q2=test2` string out by using the Uri APIs?

Thank you

Comment: You want just the [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.query.aspx) or the [QueryParsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.queryparsed.aspx) into name/value pairs?

Comment: As long you have the URL in a `std::string` you can simply use [`std::string::find('?')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the position before the substring you want.